# UNAME_SYSNAME on Python3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cython

I'm having problems installing an extention on python3.5 on Windows.

Traced it to a `IF UNAME_SYSNAME == u"Windows":` not being triggered.
According to [Cannot install pylearn2 to WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887318/cannot-install-pylearn2-to-winpython-64bit-3-4-4-1/35970202#35970202) adding the `u` should solve this but doesn't.

What is the expected output of `UNAME_SYSNAME` on Windows10 / Python 3.5?

sys.version = '3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Comment: If you really want that conditional to pass, can't you just replace it with `if True:`?

Comment: @Kevin - yes I did, but I would like it to work for the rest of the internet !

Comment: Ah, gotcha :-) Perhaps you could find someone with Windows10 / Python 3.5 and ask them what appears when they do `print(UNAME_SYSNAME)` on the line right before the conditional.

Comment: scripts should be changed to refer to `if sys.platform[:3] == 'win'`, instead of os.uname().sysname. BTW, it's a recommendation of python's docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.name

Comment: @Kevin, unfortunately it's executed by Pyrex. A 'c' preprocessor which doesn't have any i/o and I can't work out how to attach a debugger

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Cython doesn't really support python3.

If it adds support feel free to replace this answer